# How should I provide seperate layouts to different user types in NVelocity templates?

Tags: asp.net, castle-monorail, nvelocity

I'm redesigning the templates for our online store (Using Castle Monorail with the NVelocity view engine) but want to provide the old layout to certain users.

I've started out adding a variable to the PropertyBag that determines the version the user should get and set the layout to 'BaseLayout.vm' which looks like this:

```
#if($StoreVersion == 2)
    #parse("VersionTwo/DefaultLayout.vm")
#else
    #parse('VersionOne/DefaultLayout.vm')
#end
```

This works OK for the layout and I can technically use this approach in every template file, but this seems a bit long winded. Is there a better way I can mechanize this?

Comment: Is that the entire content of BaseLayout.vm or just a part of it?

Comment: That's the whole file. The idea would be to have the file that represents the action just redirect to the version specific template. I'm just curious whether there's a better way to redirect to the version specific template than that.

Comment: Why not just set the `LayoutName` property in the controller?

Comment: I thought I'd looked for that before, but I must have missed it. I can use that and override PreSendView in the abstract controller and that'll do the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a layout that "forwards" conditionally to other layouts, you can put the condition in code and set the LayoutName property in the controller.

Comment: For anyone else interested, I did the above for layouts and overrode the Process method on the controller to change the SelectedViewName for actions.

Answer (score 0):

I would crate a controller filter and override the layout name to be rendered based to your logic